# Clang error – Compiler bug or missing some detail?

Tags: c++, clang, initializer-list

While experimenting a bit with variadic templates, initializer lists, etc. I accidentally stumbled over the following nonsense-code triggering a rather interesting error message.

First, let's define a small class for testing with an overloaded `operator,()`:

```
class Dummy {
public:
    Dummy() {}
    Dummy &operator,(int) { return *this; }
};
```

Now we're using this class in the following way:

```
int test1 = (Dummy{}, 0);
```

When compiling with `clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final 334239)` this triggers a very legitimate sounding error message (since the operator essentially strips the `0` from the back):

> error: no viable conversion from 'Dummy' to 'int'

Now let's change this example a tiny bit:

```
int test2 { (Dummy{}, 0) };
```

For my understand, this should basically trigger the same message, because in the end we're trying to do the very same thing here. However, the error is different:

> error: no viable conversion from 'void' to 'int'

**Big question:** Is the `void` a bug here or is there some conversion or interpretation happening I'm simply missing?

[Code snippet on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/KGmttH)

Comment: The same happens for `const int a = 1; int& b{a};` :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in clang, try [this](https://godbolt.org/g/PivSaF), and indeed [this](https://godbolt.org/g/JBXCi7).